# How to recover interrupted do-release-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I wanted to upgrade to 22 using `do-release-upgrade`.
I started the process but the download was very slow. So, at about 5% of the download phase I interrupted the process to change mirrors. I thought it would be fine to interrupt the process and run it again to resume it. The download was at like 5%, so I thought it was just downloading the new packages, but now if I run `apt list` I see some installed packages with `focal` tag, so maybe some things were already installed after all.

Now if I run `do-release-upgrade` it just says:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

`lsb_release -a` still says I'm on 20.04:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I see that `/etc/apt/sources.list` points to `jammy` repositories, so I guess that's why `do-release-upgrade` asks me to download "all the available updates".

I have seen answers to similar questions saying that the user should revert the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the old version (in my case that would be to focal repositories), then run `do-release-upgrade` again, but I don't want to break everything, so I'm asking here to be sure.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As package manager is already in the jammy repositories, you cannot do the release upgrade anymore, but rather just upgrade all the packages themselves.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

...should do the trick.

I had a flawed USB wifi stick in my desktop machine while doing this, and the connection would drop a few times over the upgrade process. But eventually it all went just fine with the above method.